# DataTables - Requested unknown parameter on 3 of 7 Columns

Tags: datatables-1.10

I'm at my wits end with this issue and hoping someone can help.  I've perused all the other answers and none of the solutions offered are resolving my problem. The following is the JSON string:

```
{
  Description="XT86 EXTENDED WARRANTY (3 YEARS)",
  Id=88,
  InternalPartNumber="000-063",
  ManufacturerPartNumber="000-063",
  SellPrice=350.00,
  Cost=280.00,
  Category="Maintenance"
}
```

The following is my JS:

```
 $('#products').dataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "/Product/LoadProducts",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json"
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "id" },
                { data: "internalpartnumber" },
                { data: "manufacturerpartnumber" },
                { data: "description" },
                { data: "category" },
                { data: "sellprice" },
                { data: "cost" }
            ]
        });
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="shadow-lg p-1 mb-1 bg-secondary rounded">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-sm w-100" id="products">
        <thead class="bg-primary">
            <tr style="cursor:pointer;" class="text-light">
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">DCT Part #</th>
                <th scope="col">MFG Part #</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col">Sell Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Cost</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

The result is the following:

> DataTables warning: table id=products - Requested unknown parameter
> 'internalpartnumber' for row 0, column 1. For more information about
> this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Clicking OK on the error does load the table but 3 columns are missing data.

[image: Result of Query]

I've tried removing { data: "internalpartnumber" } but then I get the error on ManufacturingPartNumber.  When I remove { data: "manufacturerpartnumber" } I get the error on SellPrice.  When I remove { data: "sellprice" } I get no errors!

When I view the data from Visual Studio, the order the data is in is the same as I have it for each "index" order however when you expand each row index, it is being sorted.

[image: Visual Studio view of Data]

Any help that can be provided would be much appreciated.

The LoadProducts method is as follows:

```
 var results = (from p in _productRepository.GetAllActive
                           select new
                           {
                               p.Id,
                               p.InternalPartNumber,
                               p.ManufacturerPartNumber,
                               p.Description,
                               Category = p.ProductCategory.Display,
                               p.SellPrice,
                               p.Cost
                           });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out.  In Chrome, I selected the Network Option under the developer tools to examine the payload. What I noticed is that the first letter of the columns was lowercased which was different than what Visual Studio was showing.

[image: Chrome Network Result]

I updated my columns definitions to the following:

```
 columns: [
                    { data: "id", name: "id", autoWidth: true },
                    { data: "internalPartNumber", name: "internalPartNumber", autoWidth: true },
                    { data: "manufacturerPartNumber", name: "manufacturerPartNumber", autoWidth: true },
                    { data: "description", name: "description", autoWidth: true },
                    { data: "category", name: "category", autoWidth: true },
                    { data: "sellPrice", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '$') },
                    { data: 'cost', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '$') }
                ]
```

and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Your Columns in your DataTable are not set up in an order as your data is

HTML

```
<table id="products" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>InternalPartNumber</th>
      <th>ManufacturerPartNumber</th>
      <th>SellPrice</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
        var ret = {
        data: [
            {
                Description: "XT86 EXTENDED WARRANTY (3 YEARS)",
                Id: 88,
                InternalPartNumber: "000-063",
                ManufacturerPartNumber: "000-063",
                SellPrice: 350.00,
                Cost: 280.00,
                Category: "Maintenance"
             }
         ]
     };

    $('#products').dataTable({
        data: ret.data,
        columns: [
            { data: "Description" },
            { data: "Id" },
            { data: "InternalPartNumber" },
            { data: "ManufacturerPartNumber" },
            { data: "SellPrice" },
            { data: "Cost" },
            { data: "Category" }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Pramesh and happy new year. Although your example does work, it still doesn't work for me when I return the data thru the AJAX query using the same order you reflected in your example.  I updated my post to show the results from Visual Studio so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Happy New Year! Can you show me your LoadProducts method?

Comment: Hi Pramesh.  I added the LoadProducts method to my post.  I actually just now got it resolved.  I selected the Network Tab from the developer options in Chrome and I was able to review the payload.  It seems that the first letter of each of the columns returned was lower case.  I changed the column definitions for the Database to reflect this and everything is now working as expected.  Thanks for reaching out and assisting.  Have a great day.